# Geonode importlayers 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: postgis, geoserver, shapefile, layers, geonode

I'm trying to upload layers to Geonode using importlayers. Some of the shapefiles were successfully uploaded. However, we've encountered some errors in other shapefiles during uploading. Below is the error message.

```
================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/layers/utils.py", line 588, in upload
    title=title
  File "/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/layers/utils.py", line 470, in file_upload
    defaults=defaults
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/manager.py", line 341, in get_or_create
    return super(MultilingualQuerySet, self).get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 383, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/polymorphic/polymorphic_model.py", line 90, in save
    return super(PolymorphicModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 569, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/geonode/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/signals.py", line 74, in geoserver_pre_save
    charset=instance.charset)
  File "/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/helpers.py", line 1125, in geoserver_upload
    workspace=workspace)
  File "/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/helpers.py", line 998, in _create_db_featurestore
    raise GeoNodeException(msg)
GeoNodeException: An exception occurred loading data to PostGIS- <html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
</body></html>
```